# finding an entry in an multilevel associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to find if an entry is already in an array, but the array is a multidimensional associative array, and I cant get my head around it.

```
$products = array();
$products[] = array('product_name'=>'Burton Jacket','product_id'=>'33','product_price'=>'$342');
$products[] = array('product_name'=>'Burton Bindings','product_id'=>'41','product_price'=>'$732');
$products[] = array('product_name'=>'Bonfire Pants','product_id'=>'141','product_price'=>'$31');


if (in_array(array('product_id'=>'33'),$products)) echo 'in';
else echo 'not in';
```

So I am trying to find whether or not a product id is already contained within the array, but can't work out how to get there. I feel like I am close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop and find the element you want:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($products as $prod) {
    if ($prod['product_id'] == 33) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($found) 
    echo 'in';
else 
    echo 'not in';
```

Comment: Should I use an end() function in there as well, if the array is found? Or is it break?

Comment: Good idea.  You can add `break` to the loop.